# Can I flip android app only on HDMI screen?

Tags: android, hdmi

I have an android app that has to be restricted to portrait mode, and now I have to output it to a screen via HDMI cable. The problem is that the signal matches the screen's height but the width is letterboxed. The screen I'm using can't flip to vertical, so I have to do it by code. I basically need to display the HDMI output flipped.
[I know this can be done on the iPad](http://createdigitalmotion.com/2011/05/ipad-2-goes-native-1920x1200-output-with-thicket-devs-how-to-add-this-to-your-apps/), but I don't know how to do it on android, or whether it can even be done. 
So any ideas?

Comment: You could flip the projector on its side ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short anwer, no it can't be done, indeed on a Motorola device I would have had more of a choice. But anyway, if anyone's interested to know, what I did was create a landscape app and compose the UI so it appeared portrait, user input was a drag, but overall it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [this link](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/motorola-hdmi-dual-screen-api/)

More specifically: EXTDISP_STATUS_CONNECTION

If that doesn't work, you could always just put a menu option to switch resolutions.

Comment: That sounds great, but the problem is that the device I have to use is a Samsung Galaxy Note. Will an Motorola API work on a Samsung device?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named tvdpi and put your layouts on it